# How to get query parameters in react-router v4

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom 4.0.0-beta.6 in my project.
I have a code like following:

```jsx
<Route exact path="/home" component={HomePage}/>
```

And I want to get query params in `HomePage` component.
I've found `location.search` param, which looks like this: `?key=value`, so it is unparsed.

What is the right way to get query params with react-router v4?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

The ability to parse query strings was taken out of V4 because there have been requests over the years to support different implementation. With that, the team decided it would be best for users to decide what that implementation looks like. We recommend importing a query string lib. [Here's one that I use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string)

```
const queryString = require('query-string');

const parsed = queryString.parse(props.location.search);
```

You can also use `new URLSearchParams` if you want something native and it works for your needs

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
const foo = params.get('foo'); // bar
```

You can read more about the decision [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4410)

Comment: Do not use URLSearchParams without a polyfill. As of March 2018 Googlebot uses Chrome 41 (https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/rendering) which does not support URLSearchParams and your app will break if used in a critical path (https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams).

Comment: Comment above (from spring 2018) mentions the incompatibility of Googlebot & URLSearchParams.
However, a year later (spring 2019) the situation has improved. Since then Googlebot uses latest Chromium and thus no longer a reason to avoid URLSearchParams.
https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2019/05/the-new-evergreen-googlebot

Answer (score 27):

Another useful approach could be to use the out of the box `URLSearchParams` like this;

```js
  let { search } = useLocation();

   const query = new URLSearchParams(search);
   const paramField = query.get('field');
   const paramValue = query.get('value');
```

Clean, readable and doesn't require a module. More info below;

- https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/query-parameters
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: URLSearchParams is a browser function. What if the browser your client is using does not have it?

Answer (score 16):

The given answer is solid.

If you want to use the [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) module instead of [query-string](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string) (they're about equal in popularity), here is the syntax:

```
const query = qs.parse(props.location.search, {
  ignoreQueryPrefix: true
})
```

The `ignoreQueryPrefix` option is to ignore the leading question mark.

Comment: Nice. in January 2019, qs has 12 million weekly downloads vs 2.7 million for query-string.

Answer (score 9):

According to their docs https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters you need:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

// A custom hook that builds on useLocation to parse
// the query string for you.
function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}

function App() {
    const query = useQuery();
    console.log(query.get('queryYouAreLookingFor'));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer works well but if you don't want to install an additional package, you can use this:

```
getUrlParameter = (name) => {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    let regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    let results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  };
```

Given `http://www.google.co.in/?key=value`

```
getUrlParameter('key');
```

will return `value`

Comment: Thanks a ton mate.. the “query-string” library did not work for me for some reason, but your solution worked like a charm. I was using "react-dom": "^16.0.0",  "react-router": "^4.2.0",  "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2" and   "query-string": "^5.0.1",

Comment: this only assumes you have a single parameter in your querystring.  The OP clearly asks for how to get query params - and that's what the npm modules mentioned do.  Turn this into a function that returns an object of key/value pairs from the query string and that would be _really_ useful !

Comment: @AndyLorenz this even works when you have multiple query params, call given function with key whose value you wants to get. 
Yes method also can be transformed to give map of key values.

Comment: that would work but not a good solution @Kartik_Agarwal.  (a) It would require multiple executions of essentially the same (potentially expensive) code, (b) separate variables would need to be used for each parameter, whereas ideally you would populate an object of key/value pairs, (c) it requires you to know your parameter names, and additional checking to see whether they exist or not.  If this was my code I'd look for a regex that can pick up all parameters iteratively, but I have to admit regexs make my ears bleed!

Answer (score 5):

I was researching about params for react router v4, and they didn't use it for v4, not like react router v2/3. I'll leave another function - maybe somebody will find it helpful. You only need es6 or plain javascript.

```
function parseQueryParams(query) {
  //You get a '?key=asdfghjkl1234567890&val=123&val2&val3=other'
  const queryArray = query.split('?')[1].split('&');
  let queryParams = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < queryArray.length; i++) {
    const [key, val] = queryArray[i].split('=');
    queryParams[key] = val ? val : true;
  }
  /* queryParams = 
     {
      key:"asdfghjkl1234567890",
      val:"123",
      val2:true,
      val3:"other"
     }
  */
  return queryParams;
}
```

Also, this function can be improved

Answer (score 2):

Eh?

```
queryfie(string){
    return string
        .slice(1)
        .split('&')
        .map(q => q.split('='))
        .reduce((a, c) => { a[c[0]] = c[1]; return a; }, {});
}

queryfie(this.props.location.search);
```

Answer (score 2):

**React Router v6**

Source: [Getting Query Strings (Search Params) in React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/query-strings-search-params-react-router)

I know this was a question for v4, but with **v6** being released, here is how we can search for params in the new version of React Router.

With the new `useSearchParams` hook and the `.get()` method:

```
const Users = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  console.log(searchParams.get('sort')); // 'name'

  return <div>Users</div>;
};
```

With this approach, you can read one or a few params.

Read more and live demo: [Getting Query Strings (Search Params) in React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/query-strings-search-params-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

I just made this so don't need to change the whole code structure(where you use query from redux router store) if you update to react router v4 or higher from a lower version.

https://github.com/saltas888/react-router-query-middleware

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way without importing any additional libraries

```
const queryString = (string) => {
  return string.slice(1).split('&')
    .map((queryParam) => {
      let data = queryParam.split('=')
      return { key: data[0], value: data[1] }
    })
    .reduce((query, data) => {
      query[data.key] = data.value
      return query
    }, {});
}

const paramData = (history && history.location && history.location.search)
                ? parseQueryString(history.location.search)
                : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your route definition is like this:

```
<Route exact path="/edit/:id" ...../>

import { useParams } from "react-router";

const { id } = useParams();

console.log(id)
```

Answer (score -3):

## Very easy

just use hook `useParams()`

#### Example:

**Router**:

```
<Route path="/user/:id" component={UserComponent} />
```

**In your componen**t:

```
export default function UserComponent() {

  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <>{id}</>
  );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the use case described in the question (at least not with React-Router v4 : https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)
useParams only exposes the path params, not the search params.