# Question mark inside react router path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router

I'm trying to pass parameter inside my URL, but I have a problem with reading. I'm using react-router v4.

**URL:** http://localhost:3000/reset?token=123
I'm trying to read it this way:

```
<Route
   path="/reset?token=:token"
   component={Reset}/>
```

But this prints empty object `console.log(this.props.match.params);`. What is strange I have tried to change question mark to other character and looks like it solves my problem, but I would like to keep question mark anyway.

**URL:** http://localhost:3000/reset_token=123

```
<Route
   path="/reset_token=:token"
   component={Reset}/>
```

This already works `console.log(this.props.match.params);`. Any idea how to make question mark works also correct? Really important to me is to keep using just react-router without any external libs.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get query parameters in react-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216569/how-to-get-query-parameters-in-react-router-v4)

Comment: @MayankShukla It's similar but i would like to stay just with react-router without any external lib.

Comment: in that case you can use `this.props.location.search` then split the values to get different query parameters.

Comment: @MayankShukla Thanks! Looks like you solve my problem. Best way to solve it and keep using only react-router is `this.props.location.search.split("=")[1]`

Answer (score 3):

How did I solved this issue.

`http://localhost:3000?token=mypetismissing`

```
export default function ({ location }) {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const token = urlParams.get('token');
  console.log(myParams)

  return (
    <div>
      {token}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: works well. however, when used its important to consider browser's support for it https://caniuse.com/urlsearchparams

Answer (score 1):

You need `query-string`

Example:
http://yoursite.com/page?search=hello

```
const queryString = require('query-string')

class ProductsPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let search = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).search
    console.log(search) // ==> hello
  }

...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your path to '/reset'. That'll get the page to render with the token still in the url and you'll be able to grab that token. Happy coding :)

```
<Route
path="/reset"
component={Reset}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Extracting Query Parameters from react router path

`URL: http://localhost:3000/reset?token=123`

First import `useLocation` from `'react-router-dom`

And do this inside your functional component

```
const { search } = useLocation();

const parameters = new URLSearchParams(search);

const token = parameters.get('token');
```

Answer (score 0):

**React Router v6**

Use [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params#usesearchparams)

*Example*

```js
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

useEffect(() => {
  const token = searchParams.get('token');
  console.log(token);
}, [searchParams]);
```