# match route that has param doesn't work with react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

```
<Route path='/change-password/?resetToken=(:token)' component={()=><h1>testing</h1>} />
```

Above route don't render when I hit the url below?

```
http://localhost:3000/change-password/?resetToken=123
```

I also tried `path='/change-password/?resetToken=:token'`

Comment: try to wrap `<h1>testing</h1` into `return` and use your case with `path='/change-password/?resetToken=:token'`

Comment: seems like the problem is with the question mark you have before `resetToken`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731522/question-mark-inside-react-router-path) is a similar question on SO with no answers. I tried and it works without the `?` sign, can you change your route and make it smth like `/change-password/resetToken=:token` or do you have to keep `?` there?

Comment: I hope that is what you wanted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604617/react-router-with-optional-path-parameter

Answer (score 0):

So the main problem seems to be with the question mark in the `path`. But first you need to write `:token` instead of `(:token)`, [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#path-string) is an example format of `path` with params on github docs of the `react-router`.

I followed [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4990) github post about no way to set reserved characters in the path name, but it didn't lead me to anything. One way you could solve the problem is to define your route like `/change-password` and then in the actual component do `this.props.location.search.split("=")[1]` to get the value of the token from the search query. Here is an example:

```
class ChangePassword extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // get the token, check if it exists and do smth with it if it does
    console.log(this.props.location.search.split("=")[1]);
  }
  render() {
    return (<h1>Change password</h1>);
  };
}
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path='/change-password' component={ChangePassword} />
      <Route path='/home' component={ChangePassword} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

It seems that `react-router` doesn't handle `?` (or other reserved characters, haven't tested) in the path name, or I am seriously missing out something here and there is some magic option that makes it work :) I didn't find one but I made a working example with the code I provided on [codesanbdbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/p9vrj01oqj) with your `path` in the `Route`.