# How to get parameters on Reach Router

Tags: reactjs, url, parameters, reach-router

I've a little problem with reach router, using react hooks. I need capture the params of the route in the browser 
I tried with props of the native documentation in the web of reach router but that is not giving me the param, the route is this: 
`http://localhost:8080/home?init=true`

How to capture that variable "init"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216569/how-to-get-query-parameters-in-react-router-v4

Comment: Yeah! Is correct! But, my question is based on reach router, not react router

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Reach Router has a [useLocation](https://reach.tech/router/api/useLocation) hook you can use:

```
import { useLocation } from "@reach/router"
// then 
const location = useLocation()
```

In `location.search` is the search field, containing all the query parameters (query strings) from your URL. In your example, `/home?init=true` would return `location.search: "?init=true"`, which is a query string.

You can use [query-string](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string) library (`yarn add query-string`) to parse this:

```
import { parse } from "query-string"
// then
const searchParams = parse(location.search)
```

which would give you object 
`{init: "true"}`    you could also parse booleans with `queryString.parse('foo=true', {parseBooleans: true})`

So the full example would be

```
import { useLocation } from "@reach/router"
import { parse } from "query-string"
// and
const location = useLocation()
const searchParams = parse(location.search) // => {init: "true"}
```

Answer (score 21):

In no time, most of us will be redoing this everytime, so it's best to create a custom hook just to do this.

```
// A custom hook that builds on useLocation to parse
// the query string for you.
export const useQuery = queryParam => {
  const search = new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
  return search.get(queryParam);
};
```

Comment: This should be the answer, as it's the only one that doesn't require an additional library.