# React router with multiple params

Tags: reactjs, parameters, routes, react-router

I have a page route /movies?categoryId=21213
on this page, I have a section of actors, on the click it's should redirect to /movies?categoryId=21213/actor?actorId=234324234

how should I describe  correctly to render my latest component with an actor?
I tried

```
<Route path=`/movies/:categoryId?/:actorId?`/>
```

but that's not working

Comment: My understanding is that query string parameters aren't directly handled by react-router, you could either use multiple paths: `<Route path={['/movies/:categoryId/:actorId','/movies/:categoryId', '/movies/']} />` or handle your own query params using the location prop that the Route should make available on your component.

Comment: Here is an older question that contains an answer on how to use query params with react router. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216569/how-to-get-query-parameters-in-react-router-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216569/how-to-get-query-parameters-in-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this. Either go with query params or path params.

**Path params**

You route:

```js
<Route path='/movies/:categoryId/:actorId' />
```

Here you will have route that has two path params `/movies/1/2`.

**Query params**
Your route

```js
<Route path='/movies' />
```

So your route is only `/movies` but you pass query params to it and handle them in your component.

Example of a route with query params `/movies?categoryId=1&actorId=2`.

You can use `useHistory` hook for that purpose in your routed component.

Personally i preferred to use query params because they are easier to handle in your component, but you can pick your way from these two examples.

In your question, code is a bit wrong, because path params dont need `?` to be present in a route.