# Get url parameter using URLSearchParams in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to grab `XSOQSVPbATbRYa94ZuXs` from the `pid` parameter using
`URLSearchParams`.

Here is my URL: `http://localhost:3000/edit-product?pid=Z4HLrHGZ1ikKIwlEVkM6`

Here is my code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
      const pid = params.get("pid");

    } else {
      setProducts("");
    }
  }, [user]);
```

Any idea why I'm receiving the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.search` won't work. You need to change it by `window.location.search`

Answer (score 0):

Where does `location.search` comes from? unless you destructured it from somewhere, it should be props.location.search if you're using react-router.

[Is this question related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216569/how-to-get-query-parameters-in-react-router-v4)