# Can I use React-Router-Dom useParams() to capture a coupon code in a MERN Application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, state, url-parameters

I have been trying to figure out to how to capture a coupon code using react-router-dom's URL Parameters. I was hoping to be able to capture a coupon in the URL to set a state.

Example: https://localhost:3000/checkout?coupon=FREE3000&referrer=MATTHEW;

I want to be able to parse the URL to take the parameters Coupon & Referrer to set in the state, and to prefill a form in a checkout page.

Is this possible using React Router Dom? Are there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible via react router with a custom hook and the [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook. Anyways you will use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). There is no direct function from react router.

```js
const useQuery = () => new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search)

// use in component
const query = useQuery();

// get desired value with query.get(name)
const coupon = query.get("coupon");
const referrer = query.get("referrer");
```

Refer to this [example from the react router docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)

If you want to not use react router simply use the `window.location.search` property instead of useLocation. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, `useParams` gets the parameters after the base url not the query parameters.

For an answer on how to get the query parameters see this question [How to get query parameters in react-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216569/how-to-get-query-parameters-in-react-router-v4)